# AWS CloudFormation Transform - How do I properly return an error message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a custom AWS::CloudFormation::Transform which is attached to a Lambda function. On successful responses, as [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), I'm returning the following:

```
{
  "requestId": requestId,  //pulled from the event
  "status": "success",
  "fragment": value  //string value
}
```

This works fine. However, on an error case, I'm not entirely sure what to do. I know that according to the documentation, I should be returning the same structure but with status set to anything other than "success", and **I'm assuming** (because I can't seem to find anything to confirm this), the error message in the fragment portion. This is what I return on an error case:

```
{
  "requestId": requestId,  //pulled from the event
  "status": "failure",
  "fragment": err.code  //string value of error code
}
```

However, in my CloudFormation I get the following error:

```
Transform ############::MyCustomMacro failed without an error message.
```

I know based on the logs that the err.code has a value, so that's not the issue.

**Is there something I'm missing on how to properly return an error to CloudFormation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, but the following JSON response finally worked for me:

```
{
  "requestId": requestId,
  "status": "failure",
  "fragment": value,
  "errorMessage": customErrorMessage   // String value
}
```

Comment: It returned the custom error message to CloudFormation? Is this the result of a recent feature update?

Comment: Yes it return custom error message to cloud formation. AWS didn't document any way to return custom error message to cloud formation although there is a way. If you have used SAM, then you will have noticed that proper error message is displayed in cloud formation in case of error. SAM is using AWS macros. I don't think it's a new feature but AWS didn't mention it in the Macro docs.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out when I get a chance!

Comment: A bit delayed, but this works now. Using "errorMessage" properly returned an error back to CloudFormation

Answer (score 3):

I've done some digging and there is currently no way to return an error message with a CloudFormation macro failure. You'll have to use the CloudWatch logs for your Lambda function to debug. I've opened a feature request with the CloudFormation team.

Comment: I see, thanks for looking into it. Is this feature request on a public forum? If so, could you link it please?

Comment: It's on an internal system so not publicly linkable.